# request symfony2 time waiting

Tags: apache, symfony

I'm doing performance testing and the inspectors of chrome on network I get this:

[image](http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagen-cappeticion-8483847.html)

where I see that the page takes to load 2s being compressed with gzip (Total 270kb compressed), the problem is that looking at the first login requests takes about 1 second to complete sets waiting.

because this is so? greetings and thanks. Sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

This could be anything from webserver to bad code over to just a bad connection....

I would recommend profiling your application code with XDebug or XHprof in order to spot bottlenecks.

further

- use php fcgi/fpm
- use an opcode optimizer like apc or zend optimizer
- make sure you cache your database query results
- look for slowly executing database queries in general
- provide proper cache headers in your actions
- use a reverse proxy like varnish or at least the symfony2 internal one
- ...

... endless list. but if you follow only those in this quick list you will definitely get better results :-)